# Android firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a travel-based app where registered users could become tour guides. For this project I am using firebase database for online features. My issue is when the user wants become a guide I am taking his personal details from the regular USER node and copying it in to the GUIDES node. I want all registered users to be able to see existing guides in a chosen city.

Lets say B user wants to become a guide in London. Other users (non-guides) could find the guide by clicking on the city - in this case - London. I cannot find a way to reference nodes correctly.

```
newdatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Guides").push();

newdatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String gName, gSurname, gDate, gPhone, gPhoto, gCity;

                gName = guideName.getText().toString().trim();
                gSurname = guideSurname.getText().toString().trim();
                gDate = guideDate.getText().toString().trim();
                gPhone = guidePhoneNr.getText().toString().trim();
                gPhoto = guidePhotoURL.getText().toString().trim();
                gCity = pickedCity.getText().toString().trim();

                UserModelClass guides = new UserModelClass(gPhoto, gName, gSurname , gDate, gPhone, gCity);
                newdatabaseRef.setValue(guides);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This is how I store users' details into the new Guide node with one extra child gCity.

Firebase Structure

[image]

This is how I am trying to extract the data from the database and populate it into the appropriate city. I am trying to match the guide with the selected city. If the guide has picked London as a city I am checking it with Post cityName.

```
guideDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Guides");


mDataRef.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        final String bb = ds.getValue().toString();
                        //Log.d(TAG, "TEST " + bb);

                        guideDataRef.startAt("pickedCity").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                String cc = (String) dataSnapshot.child("pickedCity").getValue();



                                //          Exception NullPointer
                                try{
                                    if(dataSnapshot.child("pickedCity").getValue().equals(bb)){
                                        guideName.setText(cc);
                                    }
                                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                                    Log.d(TAG, "NULL");
                                }
                                //          End of Exception

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to make your question/problem stand out more. Currently i dont really understand what you want.

Comment: You should also delete this question or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499209/adding-data-into-firebase-database) bacause posting the same question again is a really bad idea. Instead you should improve your question. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I need the guides that are registered in a city (I.e. Calp) to all appear when a user selects that city. I want to reference the database nodes correctly which is why I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm just thinking out loud here:

Why don't you move your 'User' to 'Guides' when he chooses to "Upgrade" his/her status, instead of copying it, no need to use a push key, as you can easily set it with the uId and no duplicated data in your Json.

Then, I would have a node 'Cities' (which I think in your current structure is 'Post', with its properties and a List/Map of Guides of the cities containing the correspondent uId's.

'Cities' I believe you want to do it programmatically and with admin write access, for that I would figure a Firebase Function to have it with admin write access which would trigger once you push a 'Posts'...

Just an Idea...

Comment: The way I did my code is that All user profile details are linked with the Users’ node (users profile details, images etc.). If I would move users’ details to guide’ instead of copying them, the code would need to be redone from scratch.